# How to transfer Interface from Compact:Regular to Any:Any

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

I have made the mistake to build the interface using Compact:Regular.

[image]

[image]

Now my customer wants to have iPad support afterwards.

But since I have created the Interface "for iPhone only", the Any:Any interfaces are empty...

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to transfer it faster than to rebuild the whole interface? Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you will need to tweak some (if not all) constraints, but there's a pretty easy way to transfer all objects.

When selecting an object (say a label) at the **bottom of the Attributes Inspector** you will find some checkboxes called "**Installed**". Since you built the interface in Compact:Regular, you will have **2 checkboxes**. C:R and a "blank one". The blank one is for Any:Any and it will be **unchecked by default**. **Check it** and you should be done.

Then repeat the process for the rest of objects. I think that selecting all of them and checking the "Installed" checkbox will work (to save you some time).

Comment: okay. yes. i have to tweak all of the constraints, till after hitting installed, the object are all on the upper left corner cuddeling with each other. but at least i now have all my object within that view. fine so far. thank you very much.

Comment: I think you can do the same for the constraints (tick an "Installed" checkbox somewhere after selecting the constraint). You can also add new values for any constraint. Select it and left to "Constant" you will have a + icon. Click it and you can assign a new constraint for a different size class (say a different one for iPads).